# Passing messages between threads and memory management

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management

I'm writing a C++ application with two threads. Thread A will send messages to thread B. The message type could be:

```
struct MyMessageType
{
  int a;
  enum MyEnum b;
  bool someFlag;
}
```

A `std::queue<MyMessageType> messageQueue` is shared between the threads for passing messages.

In the sending thread, I'll have something like:

```
struct MyMessageType newMessage;
newMessage.a = 14;
newMessage.b = someEnumeratedValue;
newMessage.someFlag = false;
GrabTheMutexProtectingTheQueue();
messageQueue.push(newMessage);
ReleaseTheMutexProtectingTheQueue();
```

My question is regarding memory management, and is twofold:

A) How do I ensure that the pointer to `newMessage` is valid when the receiving thread gets the message? What would happen, for instance, if the function that created `newMessage` ended and `newMessage` therefore went out of scope before the receiving thread processed the message?

B) Once I can ensure that the `newMessage` pointer is valid when the receiving thread processes it, how to I free up the memory that was used by the struct?

Comment: There is no `std::queue` in C. Perhaps you meant C++?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `std::queue` `push()` function stores a *copy* of whatever you give it (see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/push/)), so you don't have to worry about it going out of scope.

The copy in the queue will survive until you delete it with `pop()`.

So, on the sending side, it's a simple matter of (for example):

```
lock_mutex();
myqueue.push (something);
unlock_mutex();
// Do whatever you want with something, the queue has a copy
```

and, at the receiving end:

```
lock_mutex();
while (myqueue.empty()) {
    unlock_mutex();
    // possibly yield to another thread
    lock_mutex();
}
something = myqueue.front();
weaveMagicWith (something);
myqueue.pop();
unlock_mutex();
```

Of course, you can re-engineer that to minimise the duration of the mutex lock on the receiving end (if, for example, weaving magic takes a long time), it's just a rough example showing one way to do it.

Comment: +1 yes.  There is no point in using a pointer type as a template parameter when the message is so small.  Pointer types only become useful when messages are larger, (eg. disk/network buffers).

Comment: If weaveMagicWith() can take some time, better to do it after releasing the mutex.  The front() call made another copy of the data so it is safe to call pop() before weaveMagicWith().

Comment: Is that right, @brian? The docs state that it returns a reference to the first item in the queue. That's not a copy, is it? That's also supported by the MS docs: "If the return value of front is assigned to a reference, the queue object can be modified".

Comment: @paxdiablo Guess it depends how 'something' was declared.  I was bad and making assumption it was simple var.

Comment: What about using atomic<std::queue<whatever>> so you can avoid the mutex calls?

Comment: @Damian I know it's a bit late, but for future reference... no, that's not how it works. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32227572) answer for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I think @brianbeuning is right, unless the `something` is being initialized as a reference, i.e. `T& something = myqueue.front();`, since copying occurs regardless of whether the `myqueue.front()` returns a reference or not.