# Atomic operation on queue<T>?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-c++

I should implement a class in Visual C++ with a queue; in this queue I've to do atomic operation. Searching on the web, I found the class std::atomic , but I keep some questions. The first is: what's the difference among:

A) `atomic <queue <T>> fifo;`

B) `queue <atomic <T>> fifo;`
 ?

The second question is: how can I make atomic operation like push?

```
push (T.load)
```

is the right solution?

The last question is: if I protect some operation on a queue with a mutex, still I have the need to do atomic operation on it?

Any advice is appreciated, Greetings

Comment: What kind of atomization do you need exactly? What needs to be atom?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The specification of my homework only says "atomic", I suppose that I've to use the methods offered by class std::atomic.

Comment: Writing a correct atomic queue is very difficult. World class experts fail at that. Do you know if you have single producer - single consumer? Single producer - multiple consumer? Multiple producer - single consumer? Multiple producer  - multiple consumer? Those are different cases with different requirements.

Comment: Multiple - Multiple ! It is an academic issue, I doubt that it could be so difficult.. probably a mutex is enough but it say "the operation of push and pop should be atomic "

Comment: I thought about lock free when you said atomic. If you just acquire a mutex at the beginning of the `pop` and `push` functions you should be good.

Comment: Also the user in the answer think that. So, I thought that I had to use the class atomic, but it is a quite impossible. You convinced me, thanks

Comment: On windows, you can use the PPL header and concurrent_* containers for thread safe standard library implementations.

Comment: In your context, atomic probably means "the operation on the queue is indivisible" -- things on the queue can happen before, or after, a given atomic operation, but cannot overlap, or happen in the middle of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A) `atomic<queue <T>> fifo;` will not even compile, because `std::atomic` requires a trivially copyable type

B) will perform atomic read or write of type T, but operations with queue (push or pop) will not be atomic.

You need to protect `queue` operations with `mutex`:

```
template<typename T>
class my_queue
{
public:
    void push( const T& value )
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_queque.push(value);
    }

    void pop()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_queque.pop();
    }

private:
    std::queue<T> m_queque;
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
};
```

Comment: thanks for answer. So, in your opinion, the sentence "insert and remove operation should be atomic " is the same of "protect the operation with a mutex " ?

Comment: If you protect operation with mutex the operation will be atomic. Added an example class to my answer.